# Finding Selected Value of Widget in Django Forms

Tags: django, django-forms

Im new to django framework ..and im having a situation when a browser back button is pressed, the form is rendered in the context of GET method without any query dict specified. However i could see the value for select widget (named as state in the below code) holding the last set value

I would like to know how we can find what value the widget is holding in the forms class

```
# in forms.py

class MyCustomForm(forms.Form):
    items = [('', 'Select Your Choice'), ('1', 'NAME'), ('2', 'AGE') ...]

    item = forms.CharField(required=True, initial='',
                                           widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'form-control'},
                                                               choices=items))

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if 'item' not in self.data:
            # WHEN BACK IS PRESSED I see we are landing here in the context of GET method.
            # And the field 'item' is holding valid value from previous selection 
            # Lets assume i selected AGE, and that is being shown properly in the page after going back
            # i would like to know how to read that selected value here


# in views.py

@never_cache
def index(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = MyCustomForm()

    return render(request, 'mypage.html', {"form": form})
```

But im able to access the value of this field from the jQuery script as during ajax call

```
$("#id_state").ready(function () {
const itemId = $("#id_item:selected").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't, this is browser cached value since the GET was just requested by the browser (before the back button). You can clear that by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to force a refresh.

The only trick is to send yourself an AJAX request with the values on the form periodically.

Comment: interesting ...let say if i have select widget whose options are based on the value of the first select widget, how in that case we should handle the code in the context of back button. Here my intent is to ensure users selections are preserved when back button is pressed